# Error: export 'MatChipList' (imported as 'i13$1') was not found in '@angular/material/chips'

Tags: angular, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have alfresco-core dependencies in my angular project and upgrading angular from 5.x to 15.x. I am  getting following errors. Any help to fix the problem is greatly appriciated.

```
 "@alfresco/adf-core": "5.1.0",
    "@alfresco/adf-extensions": "5.1.0",
    "@alfresco/js-api": "5.1.0",
    "@angular/animations": "15.2.8",
    "@angular/cdk": "15.2.8",
    "@angular/common": "15.2.8",
    "@angular/compiler": "15.2.8",
    "@angular/core": "15.2.8",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "15.0.0-beta.42",
    "@angular/forms": "15.2.8",
    "@angular/http": "7.2.16",
    "@angular/material": "15.2.8",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "15.2.8"
     .......................
```

error I am getting -

```
./node_modules/@alfresco/adf-core/fesm2020/adf-core.mjs:26320:412-429 - Error: export 'MatChipList' (imported as 'i13$1') was not found in '@angular/material/chips' (possible exports: MAT_CHIP, MAT_CHIPS_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, MAT_CHIP_AVATAR, MAT_CHIP_LISTBOX_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR, MAT_CHIP_REMOVE, MAT_CHIP_TRAILING_ICON, MatChip, MatChipAvatar, MatChipEditInput, MatChipGrid, MatChipGridChange, MatChipInput, MatChipListbox, MatChipListboxChange, MatChipOption, MatChipRemove, MatChipRow, MatChipSelectionChange, MatChipSet, MatChipTrailingIcon, MatChipsModule)

./node_modules/@alfresco/adf-core/fesm2020/adf-core.mjs:26726:100-117 - Error: export 'MatChipList' (imported as 'i13$1') was not found in '@angular/material/chips' (possible exports: MAT_CHIP, MAT_CHIPS_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, MAT_CHIP_AVATAR, MAT_CHIP_LISTBOX_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR, MAT_CHIP_REMOVE, MAT_CHIP_TRAILING_ICON, MatChip, MatChipAvatar, MatChipEditInput, MatChipGrid, MatChipGridChange, MatChipInput, MatChipListbox, MatChipListboxChange, MatChipOption, MatChipRemove, MatChipRow, MatChipSelectionChange, MatChipSet, MatChipTrailingIcon, MatChipsModule)

./node_modules/@alfresco/adf-core/fesm2020/adf-core.mjs:27421:68-85 - Error: export 'MatChipList' (imported as 'i13$1') was not found in '@angular/material/chips' (possible exports: MAT_CHIP, MAT_CHIPS_DEFAULT_OPTIONS, MAT_CHIP_AVATAR, MAT_CHIP_LISTBOX_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR, MAT_CHIP_REMOVE, MAT_CHIP_TRAILING_ICON, MatChip, MatChipAvatar, MatChipEditInput, MatChipGrid, MatChipGridChange, MatChipInput, MatChipListbox, MatChipListboxChange, MatChipOption, MatChipRemove, MatChipRow, MatChipSelectionChange, MatChipSet, MatChipTrailingIcon, MatChipsModule)

./node_modules/@alfresco/adf-core/fesm2020/adf-core.mjs:35616:114-142 - Error: export 'MatListIconCssMatStyler' (imported as 'i7$1') was not found in '@angular/material/list' (possible exports: MAT_LIST, MAT_LIST_CONFIG, MAT_NAV_LIST, MAT_SELECTION_LIST_VALUE_ACCESSOR, MatActionList, MatList, MatListItem, MatListItemAvatar, MatListItemIcon, MatListItemLine, MatListItemMeta, MatListItemTitle, MatListModule, MatListOption, MatListSubheaderCssMatStyler, MatNavList, MatSelectionList, MatSelectionListChange, SELECTION_LIST, _MatListItemGraphicBase)

./node_modules/@alfresco/adf-core/fesm2020/adf-core.mjs:43968:114-144 - Error: export 'MatListAvatarCssMatStyler' (imported as 'i7$1') was not found in '@angular/material/list' (possible exports: MAT_LIST, MAT_LIST_CONFIG, MAT_NAV_LIST, MAT_SELECTION_LIST_VALUE_ACCESSOR, MatActionList, MatList, MatListItem, MatListItemAvatar, MatListItemIcon, MatListItemLine, MatListItemMeta, MatListItemTitle, MatListModule, MatListOption, MatListSubheaderCssMatStyler, MatNavList, MatSelectionList, MatSelectionListChange, SELECTION_LIST, _MatListItemGraphicBase)

./node_modules/@alfresco/adf-core/fesm2020/adf-core.mjs:43968:146-174 - Error: export 'MatListIconCssMatStyler' (imported as 'i7$1') was not found in '@angular/material/list' (possible exports: MAT_LIST, MAT_LIST_CONFIG, MAT_NAV_LIST, MAT_SELECTION_LIST_VALUE_ACCESSOR, MatActionList, MatList, MatListItem, MatListItemAvatar, MatListItemIcon, MatListItemLine, MatListItemMeta, MatListItemTitle, MatListModule, MatListOption, MatListSubheaderCssMatStyler, MatNavList, MatSelectionList, MatSelectionListChange, SELECTION_LIST, _MatListItemGraphicBase)
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by downgrading @angular/material version from 15.2.8 to 14.2.7.

Seems it wasn't compatible with @alfresco/adf-core version I had.